# Is it necessary to create a render function in a react native application?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a list of functions that use different react-native's built-in features, I want to create a react-native class that uses those features and only use its functions and those functions will not return anything

What I have already done is returned null from my render function.
but in this case I have to create use refs to call my functions

what I'm trying to achieve is this

```
export default class Wrapper extends Component{}
```

and in my screens I want to do this

```
   export default class MyScreen extends Wrapper{
   }
```

or may be

```
   export default class MyScreen extends Component{
     componentDidMount(){ 
       Wrapper.myFunction()
     }
   }
```

`Wrapper.myFuntion()` works with all the react native's feature but doesn't render anything in view and only used for data manipulation.

Comment: If you're not using the class as a component, then don't extend the `Component` class.

Comment: But will it allow me to use react-native's module for example asyncstorage

Comment: Its not really clear what you are trying to achieve but maybe high order components will help? https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: *react-native's module for example asyncstorage* - it's unclear what you mean. You can use it apart from a component. There's no `myFunction` in the code you posted. It's unclear what it does and why it should be class *static* method and not just standalone function. If you have specific case in mind, please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that explains your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you create a class which just imports the React features you want, then that class can be called with the functions you want?

If you don't want to run through the lifecycle of React, then don't extend off of a React Component.

For example, create a class:

```
export class ReactFunctions {

    constructor (stuff : any) {
        //constructor code
    }

    public reactFunction1 () {
        //react stuff....
    }

}
```

And import it when you need it....

`import {ReactFunctions} from ....`

Following on from that, I create 'micro-services' and helper classes which don't necessarily have React based functions in. You can separate out common functionality into common modules.